# How mpos applications are implemented

Tags: android, mobile-devices, banking

I want to ask that what system is being used in mpos systems internationally: Single message system or dual message system ? if dual message systems are implemented World-wide, than we have to store card information in android application for settlement. Is it legal to store card information in an android application ? If not, than how we can implement dual message system in mpos ?

Comment: *Is it legal to store card information in an android application?* ask a lawyer, not random people on the internet

Comment: "Random People" on internet have more knowledge about banking applications, They know about the vulnerabilities of android phones and PCI standards as well than lawyers, anyway thanku

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store some information related to transaction data, which includes a masked or encrypted PAN and no sensitive data is in any of your devices. You do not need a lawyer but PCI PA-DSS guide lines, as it would be a foolish approach get a a lawyer for this reason because PCI PA-DSS certification do not validate m-POS application at all.

You can implement both single or dual message system as it depends according to the processor or switch.

Comment: Thank you very much abdullah. This really is a very good and complete answer which helps me a lot.